# Redirect a splash screen into a fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, splash-screen

I want to redirect my users to a fragment after the splash screen when they open the app. I tried to do with FrameLayout (image under) but it turn out that the app doesn't work. Thank you guys!

[This is my code for the redirection]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need an activity to host your fragment, if you place a fragment container inside an activity then move to that activity from your splash screen it will work as expected, or you can place a fragment container inside your splash screen activity and use FragmentManager to add the fragment you need.